# Model is null when I'm trying to use it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My app arhitecture is ASP.Net MVC
I'm trying to pass some data from the mssql server using entity framework ORM.

**This is the code from my action.**

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<object> myModel = new List<object>();

        var places = db.Places.Where(p => p.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId());

        myModel.Add(places);
        myModel.Add(new Place());

        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "UserName");
        return View(myModel);
    }
```

**The code from my view**

```
@model IEnumerable<object>

@{
    List<WhereWeDoIt.Models.Place> places = Model.ToList()[0] as List<WhereWeDoIt.Models.Place>;
    WhereWeDoIt.Models.Place place = Model.ToList()[1] as WhereWeDoIt.Models.Place;
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

...

<script type="text/javascript">
//Users data
var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(places));

console.log("Places test " + json);
</script>

...
```

The console will output "null"
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use viewmodel when you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once Html.Raw will get the string and put it directly in the html, try
>   to put the @Html.Raw between single quotes like:
>
> ```
> var json = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(places))';
> ```
>
> Regards,

The solution that I've provided above will set the json to json string (not object) so will not work, sorry about that. Below there is the solution (simulated and tested in my machine)

Well, we have some things going on here.

I have accomplished success in the code doing so:

```
@model IEnumerable<object>

@{
var places = Model.ToList()[0];
HypothesisWebMVC.Models.Place place = Model.ToList()[1] as HypothesisWebMVC.Models.Place;
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
//Users data
var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(places));

console.log("Places test " + json);
</script>
```

This code will set the json variable to a an object (the places list set in the controller).

I don't know what are your goal but that code that I´ve posted above will work.

Some considerations:

In the actions, when you do:

```
    List<object> myModel = new List<object>();

    var places = db.Places.Where(p => p.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId());

    myModel.Add(places);
    myModel.Add(new Place());
```

You're creating an myModel that will have in the first position and list (or IQueryable) of Place, and in the second position a single place (not a list), so you can not convert the whole model to a list.

You could use:

```
List<WhereWeDoIt.Models.Place> places = Model.ToList()[0] as List<WhereWeDoIt.Models.Place>;
```

By, when adding to the model, do a .ToList() before inserting.

Consider using a view model (an object created specific for the view)

Hope I've helped.

Regards,

Comment: {"A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Place_084A987E8F6FBE574A22E813FE314F2894AF728F244BDD6582AF50929FF1161D'."}

Comment: I've changed the solution (edited answer), take a look. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code. Edit view like this:

```
List<WhereWeDoIt.Models.Place> places = Model.ToList() as List<WhereWeDoIt.Models.Place>;
```

Model.ToList()[0] is not list.

Comment: CS0039: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WhereWeDoIt.Models.Place>' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Comment: I use this code and became List<WhereWeDoIt.Models.Place>. console.log("Places test " + json) shows places json.